# "use of undeclared type name" when using generic types

Tags: types, rust

I am writing the basic structure of a concurrent dictionary in Rust, starting with simply wrapping the existing HashMap in an `Arc::new(Mutex::new(hash_map_placeholder))`.  However, almost as soon as I start, things begin to go awry.  I am having issues with passing the `<K, V>` values down into a normal HashMap, so I can't really even start on the wrapped version.  I currently get the following error:

```
concurrent_dictionary.rs:11:39: 11:40 error: use of undeclared type name `K`
concurrent_dictionary.rs:11 impl Default for ConcurrentDictionary<K, V> {
                                                              ^
concurrent_dictionary.rs:11:42: 11:43 error: use of undeclared type name `V`
concurrent_dictionary.rs:11 impl Default for ConcurrentDictionary<K, V> {
```

Which I know is related to the type names not being passed through correctly.  How does one do this?  Even if I get rid of the default impl, I would still have to write the same thing for `ConcurrentDictionary::new()`.  Here is the code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::default::Default;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct ConcurrentDictionary<K, V> {
    data: HashMap<K, V>, 
}

impl Default for ConcurrentDictionary<K, V> {
    #[inline]
    fn default() -> ConcurrentDictionary<K, V> {
        ConcurrentDictionary {
            data: HashMap::<K, V>::new(),
        }   
    }   
}

impl<K, V> ConcurrentDictionary<K, V> {
    #[inline]
    pub fn new() -> ConcurrentDictionary<K, V> {
        Default::default()
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare any generic types you use:

```
impl<K, V> Default for ConcurrentDictionary<K, V> {
```

After that, you run into issues that `K` and `V` are *too* generic, and you need to restrict them to types that implement `Eq` and `Hash`:

```
impl<K, V> Default for ConcurrentDictionary<K, V>
    where K: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash
```

And you need to apply the same restriction to the calling function.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I was just trying to get the syntax right.  Now I'm having a document test error, but I am pretty hopeful that I can figure that one out myself.

Comment: @NuclearAlchemist feel free to come back and search for / ask another question if you get stumped on anything!